# Is there a name for non-pawn pieces?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to describe chess to a person, and one of my sentences was:

*"Two rows, one with* ***pawns*** *and another with [non-pawns]"*

What would the collection of King, Queen, Bishops, Knights and Towers be called?

Comment: See also this question: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14145

Comment: @Bad_Bishop Related, but not a dupe. But either way, I got my answer from my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, sometimes the word "pieces" itself is used for that (you can say for example: white has two pieces and three pawns left). But that isn't very practical to use.

The only solution I can think of is using **light pieces, heavy pieces and a king**.

Not a one word, but at least it can be used in your sentence.

Comment: More commonly, major and minor pieces, rather than heavy and light.

Comment: Yes you're right. Heavy and light came to my mind first...

Comment: The chessmen which are not pawns are called **pieces**. Why is that impractical?

Comment: What I would like to know is, is there a gender-neutral term that covers both pieces and pawns?

Comment: `@bof` It is impractical simply because the word "pieces" has more meanings and someone may be confused by it. To your second comment - probably there isn't such a term... :-(

Comment: @bof The term "units" is sometimes used.